# Add dates of one whole month in mysql database

Tags: mysql, date, monthcalendar

Can Any one please tell me how to add one whole month date's in mysql database. For now I'm adding one date at a time.

Comment: make one script and insert date till end of month date..

Comment: @bluto thanks for the quick reply.. can you please give me an example please?

Comment: please check `amdixon's` answer.. may be it'll help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query generates all the days of a given month.

I found this in this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/97810/75415).

When you change `NOW()` function with any date you want, it generates the dates of that month. You can also join this with your queries or you can use it with `INSERT [(col_name,...)] SELECT ...` statement to insert all the dates to a table.

```
SELECT date_field
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1) +
        INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW())-1) MONTH +
        INTERVAL daynum DAY date_field
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t*10+u daynum
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
            (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
            UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
        ORDER BY daynum
    ) AA
) AAA
WHERE MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

**plan**

> - build up decimal numbers with cross join on digits - all numbers can be expressed as :
>
>   a<sub>n</sub>10^n + .. a<sub>0</sub>*10^0
> - use **[date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)** to add start of month data filtering where less than next month start

**setup**

```
create table example
(
  `date` date primary key not null
);

drop view if exists digits_v;
create view digits_v
as
select 0 as n
union all
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all 
select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
;
```

**query**

```
insert into example ( `date` )
select date_add(date('2015-11-01'), interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day)
from digits_v a2
cross join digits_v a1
cross join digits_v a0
where date_add(date('2015-11-01'), interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day)
<     date('2015-12-01')
;
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46f8e4/1)**

---

selecting the top 10 gives

```
select `date`
from example
order by `date`
limit 10
;
```

.

```
+----------------------------+
|            date            |
+----------------------------+
| November, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 05 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 06 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 07 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 08 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 09 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 10 2015 00:00:00 |
+----------------------------+
```